# Vlc.DotNet Set Audio Track

Tags: c#, vb.net, libvlc

I use the ZeBobo5 / Vlc.DotNet file as a form control.
But a feature is missing
I can't change the sound or subtitle of the video playing

```
vlc_Control_1.VlcMediaPlayer.Audio.Tracks = 1
```

I just get a readable warning.
I can't find any way to change.
Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at https://github.com/ZeBobo5/Vlc.DotNet/blob/develop/src/Vlc.DotNet.Core/AudioManagement.cs and https://github.com/ZeBobo5/Vlc.DotNet/blob/develop/src/Vlc.DotNet.Core/SubTitlesManagement.cs

These types should be accessible from the public API of `VlcMediaPlayer`